# Button Name not able to set with setAttribute("name", "Button Name")

Tags: html, css, dom

I am creating a button on my web page but I have tried various things and I either get an error or the button is not populating with any text (see screenshot below, there should be a button called "BUTTON NAME" right above the words "Keys 2". What could I be doing wrong?

```js
dropDownButton = document.createElement("button");
dropDownButton.setAttribute("name", "BUTTON NAME")
document.body.appendChild(dropDownButton);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's setting the `name` attribute, but that doesn't affect the display at all.  (You can inspect the element in your browser's debugging tools to see the attributes.)  You can also set the *content* of the `<button>` element:

```js
dropDownButton = document.createElement("button");
dropDownButton.setAttribute("name", "BUTTON NAME");
dropDownButton.textContent = "BUTTON NAME";
document.body.appendChild(dropDownButton);
```